# Regex pattern for matching words like c++ in a text

Tags: java, regex

I have a text which can have words like c++, c, .net, asp.net in any format.

Sample Text:

> Hello, java is what I want. Hmm .net should be fine too. C, C++ are also need. So, get me C,C++,Java,asp.net skills.

I already have c,c++,java,.net,asp.net stored somewhere.
All I need is to pick the occurrences of all these words in the text.

The pattern I was using to match was `(?i)\\b(" +Pattern.quote(key)+ ")\\b` which doesn't match things like c++ and .net. So I tried escaping the literals using `(?i)\\b(" +forRegex(key)+ ")\\b` ([method link here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=96)), and I got the same result.

The expected output is that it should match(case insensitive):

`C++` : 2

`C`  : 2

`java`: 2

`asp.net` : 1

`.net` : 1

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<String> keywords; // add your keywords in this set;
String text="Hello, java is what I want. Hmm .net should be fine too. C, C++ are also need. So, get me C,C++,Java,asp.net skills.";
text=text.replaceAll("[, ; ]"," ");
String[] textArray=text.split(" ");
for(String s : keywords){
  int count=0;
  for(int i=0;i<textArray.length();i++){
    if(textArray[i].equals(s)){
      count++
    }
  }
  System.out.println(s + " : " + count);
}
```

This works most of the time. (if you want better result change the regular expression on replaceAll method.)

Comment: You forgot : ! . ? () ' " as word boundaries. Note that the probleme was not only for C++, the regex word boundary \\b doesn't work either for word with accents like in many languages

Comment: @JFB. that's true I did mention that for better result one should invest the regular expression more.

Answer (score 0):

I would choose a non-regex solution to your problem. Just put the keywords into an array, and search for each occurance in the input string. It uses [`String.indexOf(String, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String,%20int)) to iterate through the string without creating any new objects (beyond the index and counter).

```
public class SearchWordCountNonRegex  {
   public static final void main(String[] ignored)  {

      //Keywords and input searched for with lowercase, so the keyword "java"
      //matches "Java", "java", and "JAVA".

      String[] searchWords = {"c++", "c", "java", "asp.net", ".net"};
      String input = "Hello, java is what I want. Hmm .net should be fine too. C, C++ are also need. So, get me C,C++,Java,asp.net skills.".
         toLowerCase();

      for(int i = 0; i < searchWords.length; i++)  {
         String searchWord = searchWords[i];

         System.out.print(searchWord + ": ");

         int foundCount = 0;
         int currIdx = 0;
         while(currIdx != -1)  {
            currIdx = input.indexOf(searchWord, currIdx);

            if(currIdx != -1)  {
               foundCount++;
               currIdx += searchWord.length();
            }  else  {
               currIdx = -1;
            }
         }

         System.out.println(foundCount);

      }
   }
}
```

Output:

```
c++: 2
c: 4
java: 2
asp.net: 1
.net: 2
```

If you are really wanting a regex solution, you could try something like the following, which uses a [case insensitive](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE) pattern to match each keyword.

The problem is that the number of occurrences must be kept track of separately. This could be done, for example, by adding each found keyword to a map, where the key is the keyword, and the value is its current count. In addition, once a match is found, the search continues from that point, which implies that any potential overlapping matches are hidden (such as when `Asp.NET` is found, that particular `.NET` match will never be found)--this may or may not be a desired behavior.

```
   import  java.util.regex.Pattern;
   import  java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class SearchWordsRegexNoCounts  {
   public static final void main(String[] ignored)  {

      Matcher keywordMtchr = Pattern.compile("(C\\+\\+|C|Java|Asp\\.NET|\\.NET)",
         Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher("");

      String input = "Hello, java is what I want. Hmm .net should be fine too. C, C++ are also need. So, get me C,C++,Java,asp.net skills.";

      keywordMtchr.reset(input);
      while(keywordMtchr.find())  {
         System.out.println("Keyword found at index " + keywordMtchr.start() + ": " + keywordMtchr.group(1));
      }
   }
}
```

Output:

```
Keyword found at index 7: java
Keyword found at index 32: .net
Keyword found at index 57: C
Keyword found at index 60: C++
Keyword found at index 90: C
Keyword found at index 92: C++
Keyword found at index 96: Java
Keyword found at index 101: asp.net
```

Comment: both the case fail if I introduce a word beginning from 'c'. e.g. " Hello, can you find c in the corresponding text correctly?"

Answer (score 0):

Using regex I've come up with the following solution. Although it can potentially find undesired matches as described in the code comments:

```
// "\\" is first because we don't want to escape any escape characters we will
// be adding ourselves
private static final String[] regexSpecial = {"\\", "(", ")", "[", "]", "{",
    "}", ".", "+", "*", "?", "^", "$", "|"};

private static final String regexEscape = "\\";

private static final String[] regexEscapedSpecial;

static {
  regexEscapedSpecial = new String[regexSpecial.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < regexSpecial.length; i++) {
    regexEscapedSpecial[i] = regexEscape + regexSpecial[i];
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
  Set<String> searchWords = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("c++", "c",
      ".net", "asp.net", "java"));
  String text = "Hello, java is what I want. Hmm .net should be fine too. C, C++ are also need. So, get me\nC,C++,Java,asp.net skills.";

  System.out.println(numOccurrences(text, searchWords, false));
}

/**
 * Counts the number of occurrences of the given words in the given text. This
 * allows the given "words" to contain non-word characters. Note that it is
 * possible for unexpected matches to occur. For example if one of the words 
 * to match is "c" then while none of the "c"s in "coconut" will be matched, 
 * the "c" in "c-section" will even if only matches of "c" as in the "c
 * programming language" were intended.
 */
public static Map<String, Integer> numOccurrences(String text,
    Set<String> searchWords, boolean caseSensitive) {
  Map<String, String> lowerCaseToSearchWords = new HashMap<String, String>();
  List<String> searchWordsInOrder = sortByNonInclusion(searchWords);

  StringBuilder regex = new StringBuilder("(?<!\\w)(");
  boolean started = false;
  for (String searchWord : searchWordsInOrder) {
    lowerCaseToSearchWords.put(searchWord.toLowerCase(), searchWord);

    if (started) {
      regex.append("|");
    } else {
      started = true;
    }
    regex.append(escapeRegex(searchWord));
  }
  regex.append(")(?!\\w)");

  Pattern pattern = null;
  if (caseSensitive) {
    pattern = Pattern.compile(regex.toString());
  } else {
    pattern = Pattern.compile(regex.toString(), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
  }
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

  Map<String, Integer> matches = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
  while (matcher.find()) {
    String match = lowerCaseToSearchWords.get(matcher.group(1).toLowerCase());
    Integer oldVal = matches.get(match);
    if (oldVal == null) {
      oldVal = 0;
    }
    matches.put(match, oldVal + 1);
  }

  return matches;
}

/**
 * Sorts the given collection of words in such a way that if A is a prefix of
 * B, then it is guaranteed that A will appear after B in the sorted list.
 */
public static List<String> sortByNonInclusion(Collection<String> toSort) {
  List<String> sorted = new ArrayList<String>(new HashSet<String>(toSort));
  // sorting in reverse alphabetical order will ensure that if A is a prefix
  // of B it will appear later in the list than B
  Collections.sort(sorted, new Comparator<String>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
      return o2.compareTo(o1);
    }
  });
  return sorted;
}

/**
 * Escape all regex special characters in the given text.
 */
public static String escapeRegex(String toEscape) {
  for (int i = 0; i < regexSpecial.length; i++) {
    toEscape = toEscape.replace(regexSpecial[i], regexEscapedSpecial[i]);
  }
  return toEscape;
}
```

The printed result is

```
{asp.net=1, c=2, c++=2, java=2, .net=1}
```